# E1101:Instance of 'Meta' has no 'title' member

Tags: python, django, django-models

im working on a project with Django 2.1 (Python 3.7), so i used an inner class of another one, and i tried to use the "title" variable of the parent class ,but unfortunately i had an error (Instance of 'Meta' has no 'title' member),here is the code, can you guys please help me ? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yemd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__unicode__` should be `__str__` for Python 3, and that method should be declared on the Post class, not the Meta class.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear it. Please do accept the answer if it worked for you.